# fs.statSync do not recognize the file path

Tags: node.js, windows, fs

I have a problem with my nodejs script, when I try to check a file size with fs, it throws an error, "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'mypath' ", but the file exists in that path. I tried the following scripts and i get the same error:

```
const fileInfo = fs.statSync('C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\Test.xslx')
console.log(fileInfo["size"])
```

and

```
const statsPromise = async () => { 
    await ( new Promise ( () => {
        fs.stat('C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\Test.xslx', (error, fileInfo), =>{
            if(error) {
               reject(error)
            } else {
                resolve(fileInfo)
            }
        })
    }))
}
console.log(statsPromise()['size'])
```

in both cases i have the same result,
"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'mypath' "

I am working in Windows 10 OS.

Comment: Is `'mypath'` the actual path or a variable? If the second: try `fs.statSync(mypath)`

Comment: 'mypath' is the string of the path in particular 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\Test.xslx'